# convertTime Cshtml asp razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

hi guys this is my code
its cshtml

```
  <tr ng-repeat="transaction in transactions" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #88939e;">
                                             <td class="index">{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                             <td class="date">{{transaction.dateTime_}}</td>
                                             <td>{{transaction.amount  | currency | currency_d }}</td>
                                             <td>
                                                 {{ transaction.type == '3' ? 'lose': transaction.type == '2' ? 'win':transaction.type == '7' ? 'cash out':transaction.type == '9' ? ' Increase account balance' : 'Return account balance' }}
                                             </td>
                                             <td>{{transaction.credit_before | currency | currency_d }}</td>
                                             <td>{{transaction.credit_after | currency | currency_d }}</td>
                                             
                                         </tr>
```

its an pulish site and i dont have access to the controller to edit code im a php programer but this code im new on it
my propleam is {{transaction.dateTime_}} is back to persian calender in database time is english calendar but in controller convert to persain calender how can convert to english calender again can i do this with java script or just like php get data from database in loop to table from mssql in cshtml? can any body help ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't now how I can get the element from

```
<td class="date">{{transaction.dateTime_}}</td>
```

jQuery just gets

```
{{transaction.dateTime_}}
```

not the printed the value just like 2022/29/05 print this `{{transaction.dateTime_}}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).